# VB Script into Windows Forms Application

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

i'm new in the VB world, i have a script that i want to run if button is clicked.

i'm working with the VS 2010 and (window form app)
where do i need to paste the script? or should i need to open another class for that? 
that's what i have now:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

and the script that i dont know where to paste or call

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use vbscript here?  Could it not be reimplemented in the much-more functional VB.Net?

Comment: ok i got it, i just saved the script as a VBS file from the notepad and executed it from the C# file form

Comment: Okay, cool, glad you got it to work the way you wanted it to work, but you still might want to think about why you want to use something like VBScript for this.